# Why whould antlr rule won't making a nice parse tree?

Tags: antlr4

I'm trying to create a grammar that would help me parse a string like this:

[Hello:/c=0.3//a=hi/] [what:/c=0.4/] [are:/c=0.6//a=is/]

This is my grammar:

```
grammar MyGrammar;
WS: [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip; // skip spaces, tabs, newlines

sentence: WORD+;

WORD: '[' WORD_DESCRIPTOR ']';

WORD_DESCRIPTOR: WORD_IDENTIFIER ':' WORD_FEATURES_DESCRIPTORS;

WORD_IDENTIFIER: STRING;

WORD_FEATURES_DESCRIPTORS: WORD_FEATURE_DESCRIPTOR+;

WORD_FEATURE_DESCRIPTOR: '/' WORD_FEATURE_IDENTIFIER '=' WORD_FEATURE_VALUE '/';

WORD_FEATURE_IDENTIFIER:
    C_FEATURE | A_FEATURE
    ;

C_FEATURE: 'c';
A_FEATURE: 'a';

WORD_FEATURE_VALUE: STRING | NUMBER;

fragment LETTER : LOWER | UPPER ;
fragment LOWER  : 'a'..'z' ;
fragment UPPER  : 'A'..'Z' ;
fragment DIGIT  : '0'..'9' ;
fragment INTEGER: DIGIT+ ;
fragment NUMBER: INTEGER (DOT INTEGER)? ;
fragment STRING: LETTER+ ;
fragment DOT: '.' ;
```

The problem is that the parse tree has only one level.
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The parse tree is flat because that is what you specified--"sentence: WORD+;" So, the parse tree will be one root node for "sentence" and children that are leaves of the tree for for each "WORD". Lexers produce tokens, which do not have a tree structure. A token has basically token type (an int) and text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your parse tree shows up the way it does because all tokens are leaf nodes, and all parser rules are internal nodes. Since you only have a single parser rule (`sentence`) and the rest are all tokens, this  is the parse tree:

```
      sentence
     / |    | \
    /  |    |  \
WORD WORD WORD WORD ...
```

You should see tokens as the atoms that your language is built from. Once you start creating tokens like `TOKEN : TOKEN_A | TOKEN_B;`, then that is often better defined as a parser rule: `token : TOKEN_A | TOKEN_B;`.

Try something like this instead:

```
sentence                 : word+ EOF;
word                     : '[' word_descriptor ']';
word_descriptor          : word_identifier ':' word_feature_descriptors;
word_identifier          : STRING;
word_feature_descriptors : word_feature_descriptor+;
word_feature_descriptor  : '/' word_feature_identifier '=' word_feature_value '/';
word_feature_value       : STRING | NUMBER;
word_feature_identifier  : C_FEATURE | A_FEATURE;

C_FEATURE : 'c';
A_FEATURE : 'a';
NUMBER    : INTEGER (DOT INTEGER)?;
STRING    : LETTER+ ;
WS        : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip; // skip spaces, tabs, newlines

fragment LETTER  : LOWER | UPPER;
fragment LOWER   : [a-z];
fragment UPPER   : [A-Z];
fragment DIGIT   : [0-9];
fragment INTEGER : DIGIT+;
fragment DOT     : '.';
```

which will create the following parse tree for your input:

[image]